# How to compare two age distributions in a population of people?

Tags: anova, t-test, cohens-d

I have data on a number of clubs and the ages of their members broken down into categories from 0 to 94 and then a final category of 95+. I have about 10,000 clubs and I need to compare how similar the age profiles of two arbitrarily chosen clubs in the data set are.

I've tried using Welsh's t-test but I am unable to interpret the results and I am not sure this is appropriate, although I cannot guarantee that all clubs (samples within the population) will have a shared variance.

Another caveat to this is that I am trying to identify how similar two clubs are on a number of measures. One of these measures is "annual revenue" and I am using cohen's d to calculate the similarity of one club to another; another measure is the cohen's d of the "number of staff" who work at the club.

I then add the absolute values of the two cohen's d calculations above and the smaller this value is, the more similar I consider two clubs  to be. Given that cohen's d is not a bounded measure I am concerned I cannot just add this to the value from a Welsh's t-test.

Some advice on how to go about this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to test the null hypothesis that, given two clubs, the mean age for those two clubs are the same?

Comment: The fundamental goal is to be able to quantify how similar two clubs are based on their annual revenue, the number of staff they have and the distribution of ages of their members. So if club A makes 100 in annual revenue and club B makes 200 in annual revenue and the standard deviation of annual revenue in the entire dataset is 50 I will calculate the absolute value of (100 - 200)/50 = 0.5. I then add 0.5 to the same value I calculate for the number of staff. So let's say club A has 10 staff and club B has 8 staff and the standard deviation in the dataset is 5 (10 - 8)/5 =0.4.

Comment: So if I add these two values together 0.4 + 0.5 I get a value that quantifies how similar club A is to club B. However, I want to incorporate "age distribution" in this measure but "age distribution" is a set of ages and the corresponding number of members of that age so I am not just comparing one number to another.

Comment: You can look at histogram similarities using chi-squared distances. That provides a measure of difference between histograms.

Comment: Thanks for this. So if I have the following data: Club A - 0: 0, 1: 3. 2: 8, 3+: 9 and Club B - 0: 1, 2: 6, 3+: 7 where x: y denotes "age: number of members of that age". Would I get (0-1)^2/(0+1) + (3-6)^2/(3+6) + (9-7)^2/(9+7) = 2.25. Would I then square root this or just add this value to my other two values?

Comment: If that's what you want to report. Depends on what you're using these values for.